# Showing that the large $x$ limit of $e^{-x}$ is zero by considering the negative gradient of the partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, asymptotics

I know that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}=0$$

If I consider the partial sums of the respective Maclaurin series,

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i} x^i}{i!}, \,\, n=1,2,\dots
$$
its seems that despite their divergence to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ for large $x$, near zero these sums look like they begin to descend, and we can guess then that the $n$th partial sum will converge for large $n$ to a function of $x$ whose limit is zero as $x \to \infty$.
[image]
The reason this happens appears to be that the larger powers of $x$ only take over for large values of $x$, since we are scaling each term by $\frac{1}{i!}$, and so near zero all the partial sums start to converge to $e^{-x}$.

If I consider contributions in pairs,

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i} x^i}{i!} = 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}-\frac{x^{2i-1}}{(2i-1)!}\right)
$$

then one can see that there is a turning point in the contributions of this sum when $$\frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}-\frac{x^{2i-1}}{(2i-1)!}=0$$
Before this value of $x$ (which makes the above difference equal zero) we add on something negative, but after we add on something positive, and this eventually goes to $+\infty$ (for even-indexed sums). This turning point is the root of a polynomial, for example $$p_{2}(x)  = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x = 0.$$ If I call this root $s_2$, such that $p_{2}(s_2)=0$, and consider the next contribution $$p_{4}(x)  = \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{6}x^3 = 0,$$ and its root $s_4$ such that $p_{4}(s_4)=0$, and so on, **the question is**, if for all positive $i$
$$
s_2 < s_4 < s_6 < \dots < s_{2i} < s_{2i+2}
$$
such that these roots strictly increase with higher-order contributions, does that mean the function $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i} x^i/i!$ (the solid black line in the figure above) converges to zero as $x \to \infty$? It would seem this would mean the function would decrease for larger and larger intervals of $x$, until it decreases for all $x \geq 0$, and therefore, since we know its non-negative, must converge to 0.

### Some context

The reason this is important concerns situations where one needs to prove that a difficult oscillating sum converges to zero for large $x$, **but cannot first show it has a closed form**, as we did with $e^{-x}$.

Consider for example the sum

$$
f(x) = \sum _{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i \left(3^{\frac{3 i}{2 i+4}} \left(x\sqrt{\pi } \right)^{\frac{i^2-3 i+2}{i+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(i+2) 2^{i-1}} i!}
$$

and consider evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. Here is a plot of the sum and its partial sums.

[image]

We don't know this limit (can this be evaluated?). I am trying to show it's zero. This appears to be about showing the partial sums near zero converge to a function that is always decreasing (and non-negative, which it is since, for context, $f(x)$ represents a probability).

Is it sufficient to consider the roots of the partial sums, and show they are strictly increasing with the order of the partial sum?

Comment: Nice question. Where does the sum come from?

Comment: It is an alternating sum of factorial moments. Consider the non-negative, integer valued r.v. $X$, and its $r^{\text{th}}$ factorial moment $E_{r}[X]$. Then we have that
$$
P(X=0) = \sum _{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i E_{r}[X]}{ i!}
$$
Consider moments 
$$E_{r}[X](x) = \frac{ \left(3^{\frac{3 i}{2 i+4}} \left(x\sqrt{\pi } \right)^{\frac{i^2-3 i+2}{i+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(i+2) 2^{i-1}}}$$
Then
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} P(X=0) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum _{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i \left(3^{\frac{3 i}{2 i+4}} \left(x\sqrt{\pi } \right)^{\frac{i^2-3 i+2}{i+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(i+2) 2^{i-1}} i!}$$